# Similar Triangles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking to improve my programming skills with this question. I believe I am making a mistake placing a tikzpicture within a tikzpicture? Any suggestions how to make this better and more flexible so one can vary the output according to ones needs? This is exactly what I want but I want to improve the programming.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (-3,0) {\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]%,cap=round,>=latex]
\coordinate [label=left:$B$] (B) at (0:0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$A$] (A) at (60:1.5cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (20:1.8cm);
\filldraw[fill=orange!50!white, draw=black] (B) -- node[above left] {c} (A) -- 
node[above right] {b} (C) -- node[below] {a} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}};
\node at (3,0) {\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]%,cap=round,>=latex]
\coordinate [label=left:$Y$] (Y) at (0:0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$X$] (X) at (60:.5cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$Z$] (Z) at (20:.6cm);
\filldraw[fill=orange!50!white, draw=black] (Y) -- node[above left] {z} (X) -- 
node[above right] {y} (Z) -- node[below] {x} (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you should not nest `tikzpicture`s, and all you need is to use `pic`s.

Comment: I remember you saying this. How can I give them names? Should I use the \def command ?

Comment: I appended two pics examples to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the simplest way is to replace the inner `tikzpicture`s by scopes and implement the position by simple shifts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-3cm,scale=2]%,cap=round,>=latex]
\coordinate [label=left:$B$] (B) at (0:0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$A$] (A) at (60:1.5cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (20:1.8cm);
\filldraw[fill=orange!50!white, draw=black] (B) -- node[above left] {c} (A) -- 
node[above right] {b} (C) -- node[below] {a} (B);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm,scale=2]%,cap=round,>=latex]
\coordinate [label=left:$Y$] (Y) at (0:0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$X$] (X) at (60:.5cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$Z$] (Z) at (20:.6cm);
\filldraw[fill=orange!50!white, draw=black] (Y) -- node[above left] {z} (X) -- 
node[above right] {y} (Z) -- node[below] {x} (Y);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have the same thing and want to place it all over, use `pic`s, but since these are only two triangles here with different labels, it is perhaps easier to use scopes. However, as you asked in the comments, here is the `pic`s variant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
3angle/.style n args={6}{code={\coordinate [label=left:$#2$] (B) at (0:0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$#1$] (A) at (60:1.5cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$#3$] (C) at (20:1.8cm);
\filldraw[fill=orange!50!white, draw=black] (B) -- node[midway,above left] {#6} (A) -- 
node[midway,above right] {#5} (C) -- node[midway,below] {#4} (B);}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[scale=2] at (-3,0) {3angle={A}{B}{C}{a}{b}{c}};
\pic[scale=0.75] at (3,0) {3angle={X}{Y}{Z}{x}{y}{z}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that one might be able to cook down the number of parameters to 3 if you always label the edge opposite a given corner by the lowercase letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
3angle/.style n args={3}{code={\coordinate [label=left:$\MakeUppercase{#2}$] (B) at (0:0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$\MakeUppercase{#1}$] (A) at (60:1.5cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$\MakeUppercase{#3}$] (C) at (20:1.8cm);
\filldraw[fill=orange!50!white, draw=black] (B) -- node[midway,above left] {#3} (A) -- 
node[midway,above right] {#2} (C) -- node[midway,below] {#1} (B);}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[scale=2] at (-3,0) {3angle={a}{b}{c}};
\pic[scale=0.75] at (3,0) {3angle={x}{y}{z}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```